# Controllers organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I wanted to ask something, I was starting a project from scratch but I was thinking, in my routes I have a namespace :admin, should I have a segmentation of responsibilities like this?.

scholarship_controller => for all the crud and functions that are proper of the scholarship, but If I'm gonna have functions of the scholarship that are handled by admin, should I have a folder called Admin and inside have another scholarship_controller that just handle the admin functionality of the scholarship? or is this wrong will this provoke a mess?

Comment: if it's provoking a mess, go and refactor it.

Comment: if you are going to have an admin section, keep the admin logic in separate controller under admin namesapce